# boto.sns.connect_to_region eu-central-1 FAILED

Tags: python, boto, amazon-sns

I use the same aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key to do boto.sns.connect_to_region, and it failed only on 'eu-central-1'.  All other regions are OK.  Could anyone help?

```
sns_conn = boto.sns.connect_to_region('eu-central-1', aws_access_key_id=access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key, validate_certs=False)

print sns_conn
# Output: None

sns_conn = boto.sns.connect_to_region('us-west-1', aws_access_key_id=access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key, validate_certs=False)

print sns_conn
# Output: SNSConnection:sns.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: What is your boto version?

Comment: Thank you... You just answered my question.  My boto version does not support the new region yet.

Answer (score 0):

Boto v2.49.0 works on my end with AWS 'eu-central-1' region

```
#!//opt/boxen/homebrew/bin/python

import boto.sns
import json

sns_conn = boto.sns.connect_to_region('eu-central-1',aws_access_key_id='access_key_id',aws_secret_access_key='secret_access_key', validate_certs=False)

print sns_conn
#Output: SNSConnection:sns.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

Let us know if upgrading Boto version doesn't resolve this issue?